# Regex.IsMatch for only letters and numbers

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to write an expression that allows only letters and numbers.
Why this expression is false:

```
Regex.IsMatch("1298red673419dfRED2", "[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g")
```

I am using VB.NET in VS2019

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch("1298red673419dfRED2", "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")`

Comment: Wiktor, thank you for the answer. It is working. 
Do you know why the behavior is the same if I use * instead of + as you put in your answer?

Comment: It is not the same, try with `"a"` and `""` as input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I understand now: one accepts empty strings, and the other one doesn't. Thank you for your help.